# Flip box with TweenMax

Tags: jquery, css, gsap

I have created the following flip box but the problem is that when I open the collapse it has the height equal with both sides of the flip box instead to cover only the active one. Has anyone any idea how to solve this? Please

https://jsfiddle.net/qnwtLbzs/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        TweenMax.set('#flipContainer, #testCard',{
        perspective:500
        });
    TweenMax.set($('#testCard'),{
        transformStyle:'preserve-3d'
        });
    TweenMax.set('#testCard div',{
        backfaceVisibility:'hidden'
        });
    TweenMax.set('#back',{
        rotationX:-180
        });

    var flipped=false;
    $('#testCard').click(function(){
        if(!flipped){
            TweenMax.to($(this),1,{
                rotationX:180,
                onComplete:function(){
                    flipped=true;
                    }
                });
        }
        else{
            TweenMax.to($(this),1,{
                rotationX:0,
                onComplete:function(){
                    flipped=false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Im not quite sure what the problem is, can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: OK. This is the version which has a right height when I open it. But I've commented the back face just to show you how is the height. https://jsfiddle.net/qnwtLbzs/3/ in this version I have the height of the other face even if is not visible https://jsfiddle.net/qnwtLbzs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Please define height for content div and then over hidden. Try it, Hopefully it will fix your problem.

Here is updated style for the same.

```css
#collapse > .content {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:357px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
```